# Remove search entry from resolv.conf in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

My /etc/resolv.conf (and also /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf) contain a `search` entry for `wifi.ns.nl` that I did not put there and do not want there. It seems related to a problem I have now in that I cannot resolve some web addresses. The resolv.conf files are managed by systemd-resolved and tell me not to edit them manually. If I do that anyway nothing changes and if I restart sytsemd-resolvd it changes the resolv.conf files back to their original state.

The `search wifi.ns.nl` line probably appeared after I tried to connect to a captive wifi network run by `ns.nl`. After connecting to the wifi, but before accepting the terms on the web portal, I tried to connect with SSH to a server. That didn't work, and accessing any other website through the wifi also did not work. When I came home and connected to my home network, connecting to the server I wanted to connect to still didn't work, and `systemd-resolve` now says `resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found` for that server and for *.wifi.ns.nl. (I can still connect to the server using the ip address, and I can resolve the name using `dig` on a remote dns server, so the problem is only my local DNS resolver.)

If I do `systemd-resolve --status` it also tells me 'wifi.ns.nl' is one of my global DNS Domains.

Apparently something somewhere has remembered some setting probably related to the captive wifi network and `wifi.ns.nl`. I've tried restarting `systemd-resolved`, `networking`, `network-manager`, but the search entry is still there.

(I also did a `sudo grep -R wifi.ns.nl /etc`, it doesn't find 'wifi.ns.nl' anywhere else under `/etc` other than the resolv.conf file)

How can I remove that search entry, other than rebooting my system?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be the bug described [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6976). If both systemd-resolved and the `resolvconf` package are installed they fight over who gets to manage `/etc/resolv.conf`. If there are any `search` lines in that file these domains break for a reason I don't quite understand yet.

In my case, with both installed `/etc/resolv.conf` was a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. After removing the `resolvconf` package it became a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` and after restarting the `systemd-resolved` service that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and the simplest solution is to edit `/etc/resolve.conf` and remove the 'search' lines.

No restarting required, and things work again.

This, however, is not a *solution*, as any time I use my vpn or connect my laptop to the work network, it happens all over again. I too don't understand the bug (haven't even tried yet, as I have too many other new annoyances since the switch from Unity on 17.04 to Gnome on 17.10). But that's an answer that addresses your (or others coming later) problem without a reboot.